# A paper about the economics of (physical) power?

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request

A couple of years ago I came across a economics paper that derived a microeconomic model in which if you include (physical) power and competition it led to some particular equilibriums. I do not remember exactly what it was about and whether what I just described about it is correct, but something in those lines. I believe that I remember the paper having something of "rumble in the jungle" in the paper title. I also believe that the paper was written by a (fairly) famous economist. Does anyone by any chance know the name of this paper and by whom it was written? I feel really sad that I lost this paper and would like to find it again as it was very interesting. I would be very grateful if anyone can help my find the paper!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Piccione, Michele, and Ariel Rubinstein. "[Equilibrium in the Jungle.](https://arielrubinstein.tau.ac.il/papers/77.pdf)" *The Economic Journal* 117.522 (2007): 883-896.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you so much, you made my day!